# AngularJs - Dynamic tabs - should adjust itself

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Html code is as below

```
<div>
    <ul data-ng-repeat ="tab in tabs">
          <li data-ng-class="{active: tab.selected == 'true'}"  message-key="Tab">
          </li>      
     </ul>
</div>
```

The screen looks like this:
[image]

### One part of the screen has a panel with tabs - tabs can be between 1 to 10. The requirement is if the tabs do not fit in the space, their size should be reduced dynamically so as to fit them. No scroll bars are allowed. We use Angularjs and bootstrap. Any ideas?

Made changes as per the suggestions.
The screen looks like this (the tabs are going outside the screen, font size does not change)[image]

Html Code

```
    <div  class="divtab" >
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" data-ng-repeat ="tab in tabs">                                                                                
          <li data-ng-class="{active: tab.selected == 'true'}" message-key="Tab">  </li>      
         </ul>
</div>
```

Css classes

```
.divtab {
   width: 100%;
   display: -webkit-box;
   display: -webkit-flex;
   display: -ms-flexbox;
   display: flex;
   -webkit-box-align: center;
   -webkit-align-items: center;
   -ms-flex-align: center;
   -ms-grid-row-align: center;
   align-items: center;
   height: 36px;
   margin-bottom: 15px;
   padding: 0;
}
.divtab > ul {
   list-style: none;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   height: 44px;
}
.divtab > ul > .active {
   background: #0e847d;
   color: #fff;
   border-radius: 2px 2px 0 0;
}
.divtab > ul > li {
  padding: 0 20px;
  height: 100%;
  display: -webkit-inline-box;
  display: -ms-inline-flexbox;
  display: inline-flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -ms-grid-row-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: seems like you are trying to ask about bootstrap and css, which are the tools that handle layout, not javascript or AngularJs, which handle data processing.

Comment: you could just set the style on the containing element to be `display:flex` with `flex-wrap:no-wrap`, which I think would solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

```
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs" data-ng-repeat ="tab in tabs">
  <li  data-ng-class="{active: tab.selected == 'true'}" message-key="Tab"></li>
</ul>
```

Use above code snippet. Use bootstrap nav and nav-tabs calass

Answer (score 0):

Here is the exaple

> Js

```
$scope.tabs = [
    {id: 1, name: 'tab1', selected: true},
    {id: 2, name: 'tab2', selected: false}    
   ];
```

> Html

```
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs" data-ng-repeat ="tab in tabs">
  <li  data-ng-class="{'active': tab.selected}"><a data-toggle="tab">{{tab.name}}</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I have updated my query with the new info. Please comment.

Comment: please can you show your example in plunker or stackBitz,
and my above answer is correct for tabs so please accept answer and please voteup